# extracting list from an object and using its methods

Tags: c#

i'm trying to get a list to a function while the variable getting the list is an object.
i'm trying to create a generic option to the function that there is no need to set the function for the list specific.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car Ford = new Car();
        Car Toyota = new Car();
        Motorcycle Kawasaki = new Motorcycle();
        Bike Zebra = new Bike();
        List<Vehicle> Garage = new List<Vehicle>();
        Garage.Add(Ford);
        Garage.Add(Toyota);
        Garage.Add(Kawasaki);
        Garage.Add(Zebra);
        Class1 c1 = new Class1(Garage);
    }
 }
class Class1
{
    public Class1(object obj)
    {
       //cannot find the way to extract the list and its method 
    }

}
```

i can see in the obj the list but i'm not able to use it(no posiblity to loop the classes and not using their public methods.
i know there is some posiblity to use reflection but i managed only to work with one class only but not with a list.
any assistance here?

Comment: I dont undestand? Just replace object in the constructer with list<vehicle> and pass garage as a argument?

Comment: I don't want to write list<vehicle> because i want the object to be able to get and there i will use reflection in order to use the methods

Comment: So which object are you talking about?

Comment: class Class1
{
    public Class1(object obj)
    {
       //cannot find the way to extract the list and its method 
    }

}

Comment: @YDG what are you trying to *actually do*? This is the wrong approach.

Comment: i want to have a function that can get any list and use its methods in the classes

Comment: @YDG That is not a problem statement. That is a proposed solution. And it's the wrong one. What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Generic for this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car Ford = new Car();
        Car Toyota = new Car();
        Motorcycle Kawasaki = new Motorcycle();
        Bike Zebra = new Bike();
        List<Vehicle> Garage = new List<Vehicle>();
        Garage.Add(Ford);
        Garage.Add(Toyota);
        Garage.Add(Kawasaki);
        Garage.Add(Zebra);
        Class1<Vehicle> c1 = new Class1<Vehicle>(Garage);
    }        
}

 class Bike : Vehicle
{
}

 class Car : Vehicle
{
}

 class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
}

 class Vehicle
{
}

class Class1<T> 
{
    public Class1(List<T> obj)
    {
        foreach (var item in obj)
        {

        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                //this is how you run a method
                item.GetType().GetMethod(methodname).Invoke(item, null);
            }

Comment: i don't get it ... what you need now ??